# Poisson kernel for fractional Laplacian

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Does the Poisson kernel for fractional Laplacian $(-\Delta)^s$ exist for a smooth bounded domain with two boundaries. If so, is there a upper and lower bound for the Poisson kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it does! Estimates of the Poisson kernel (and closely related bounds for the Green function) were studied already in the 90s by two independent groups of people: Bogdan, Byczkowski and Kulczycki, and Chen and Song. You can find the estimate you need in Theorem 1.5 in:

- Z.-Q. Chen, R. Song, *Estimates on Green functions and Poisson kernels for symmetric stable processes*. Math Ann 312, 465–501 (1998), [DOI:10.1007/s002080050232](https://doi.org/10.1007/s002080050232).